# Can not enableIndexedDbPersistence from firebase v9 in a nextjs pwa

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I can't firebase v9 enableIndexedDbPersistence in a nextjs pwa.

this erros are trow

index.js // firebase main

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CONFIG

const app = initializeApp(JSON.parse(firebaseConfig))
export const db = getFirestore(app)

// enableIndexedDbPersistence(db) //   >>>  if put here it said can't be invoked after getFirestore or any other funtion

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const storage = getStorage(app)
```

So where should i invoke

Answer (score 0):

The `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)` function must be called before . From its documentation:

> Must be called before any other functions (other than
> {@link initializeFirestore}, {@link (getFirestore:1)} or
> {@link clearIndexedDbPersistence}.

So `getFirestore(app)` is actually exempted from that, in contrast what you stated in the comment of your code snipped:

> // >>> if put here it said can't be invoked after getFirestore or any other function

Consequently, my guess would be that you might use the exported `db` before the promise of `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)` completes.
You could resolve this in different ways, such as wrapping it in a service or method and make sure you are `await`-ing the promise, or generally change your app that `db` is not used right away.

In my Ionic PWA app, I'm successfully using the following:

```js
import { getFirestore, enableIndexedDbPersistence } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)
    .then(() => console.log("Enabled offline persistence"))
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.code == "failed-precondition") {
        // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
        // in one tab at a a time.
        // ...
      } else if (error.code == "unimplemented") {
        // The current browser does not support all of the
        // features required to enable persistence
        // ...
      }
    });
```

This is very similar to your snipped indeed. But the first access to Firestore happens after via user interaction, and not right away.